# Can we access a file of public folder of iOS File APP in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file, filesystems

I am extremely stucked in accessing a file which is kept inside File APP in our iPhone.

I need to access this srijan.json file in our iOS APP. Is this possible or not. And if possible then how we can achieve.

Location of Srijan.json is inside File APP -> On My iPhone

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: Open saved image inside the native Files app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71252506/ios-open-saved-image-inside-the-native-files-app)

Comment: Your app can't just reach out and open it because the file is outside your app's sandbox.  You can use [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) to let the user select the file or you can expose your app's document directory as  Ptit Xav suggested and have the user copy the file into your app's documents

Comment: did you able to do it ?
Or its not possible ?